# PRI and BRI cards

Tags: telephony

I have successfully configured a BRI(B400p) card on Asterisk server, I have some basic skills about B-D channels, TE/NT difference, etc.
But I'm still a little confused about the PRI use on Asterisk(or other PBX). If I had a BRI card, I can configure it attaching to the ports 4 isdn phones, or 3 isdn phones and one isdn TA, etc..
If I put a PRI card on Asterisk what I can attach to it? As I know phones and TA are only for BRI, and is not possible to connect a BRI "port" to a PRI "port". The question is: what can be the use of a PRI card? Connect to a existing PRI line only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Basic Rate Interface (BRI) provides two data channels while a Primary Rate Interface (PRI) provides 30 channels.

While ISDN phones use BRI interfaces, PRI interfaces are used for trunks toward the PSTN or other PBXes. Also, there are multiplexers/converters that concentrate multiple BRIs to a single PRI.

Comment: T1-PRI is 23+1, E1-PRI is 30+1.

Answer (score 1):

The BRI is the basic equivalent of a POTS line. One can hang a single phone off of it. But it's common in business to bring BRI's into a PBX (if not POTS.) [ISDN phones, and BRI's in general, were never very popular in the US.]

A PRI is the ISDN equivalent of a T1/E1. (23B/30B) The PRI runs into whatever equipment you need... PBX, router, modem bank, video conference system, etc. I've never heard of anyone making a phone with a PRI interface. (what would be the point?)

If the hardware can function as a switch, back-to-back BRI/PRI may be possible. (i.e. PRI directly between two PBX's.)